# Detail view on Map in Iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview

In my app,I implemented a map View & added the annotations.

But now, i want to show the detail view on click of annotation in popover.Till now, i did this on click of calloutAccessoryControl.

But the popover must be start with just beside of annotation & 
 I don't want to show the calloutAccessoryControl or any black default label.

My code is:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)myMap viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
AnnotationImageView *myLocationImage = (AnnotationImageView *)[map dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultID];

    if (myLocationImage == nil )
    {
        myLocationImage = [[[AnnotationImageView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultID] autorelease];
        myLocationImage.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];     
    }

    myLocationImage.locationID = [currentAnnotation locationID];
    myLocation = myLocationImage;

    [myLocation setEnabled:YES];
    [myLocation setCanShowCallout:YES]; 

    return myLocation;
}


- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)myMap annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{

detailsView *popUp=[[detailsView alloc] initWithNibName:@"detailsView_ipad" bundle:nil];


        popView = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:popUp];

        popView.delegate =self;

        [popView setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(600, 500)];



AnnotationImageView *myLocationImage = (AnnotationImageView *)view;
        popUp.locationID = myLocationImage.locationID;

[popView presentPopoverFromRect:control.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

}
```

**Is there any method call when annotation is clicked??**

**How can i do this??**

** I want to show like this**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the class which implements the `MKMapViewDelegate` you can implement the `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:` method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)aView {
    //do something...like push a new UIViewController

    if (UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone == UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()) {
        //only do something when the app is running on the iPhone
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! But sorry to say that your method is not called any time.

Comment: You can check if the app is running on Phone or Pad with `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone == UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()`. You can set such a if clause in the implementation of `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:`. An empty implementation on the iPhone should be fine.

Comment: can you post some code to call this method?? I don't know this.

Comment: The method should be called, I tested it with a new project. Please add a `NSLog(@"...");` statement at the beginning of the method. Please take a look at the MKMapViewDelegate Protocol reference to see the description of the methods.
Also check if you set the `delegate`of your MKMapView instance to the correct class (either in the Interface Builder or in code: e.g.: `_myMapView.delegate = self`).

Comment: what should be print in NSLog & i tried but your method is not called.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you write in NSLog, e.g. `NSLog(@"didSelectAnnotationView was called")`, you can also set a breakpoint. I can only think that an outlet or delegate isn't set correctly, but I'am not sure...

Comment: I've uploaded my test to github: https://github.com/sebk/MapTest
Maybe you can find the difference why the method isn't called in your app.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply.. I extremely sorry but yes method is called is Demo Project. But i think i  used custom annotation class & that is why in my project still your method is not called.

Comment: @Sebastian, do you know if it's possible to do something similar in iPhone?

Comment: Maybe you could try to use a UIPopover implementation for the iPhone (e.g. https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover). Another good project is https://github.com/grgcombs/MultiRowCalloutAnnotationView.